# Spring Security OAuth2 configuring failureUrl makes the url inaccessible

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring security based boot application for which I have configured an endpoint names `/test` for which I return a `test.html` page

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public String test() {
  return "test.html";
}
```

The endpoint works fine by itself, however if I set it as an OAuth2 `failureUrl` it becomes unavailable...

```
http.csrf().disable()
      .httpBasic().disable()
      .formLogin().disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/test").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .oauth2Login()
      .failureUrl("/test");
```

Is this expected behavior? When I do this, spring security properly redirects to `/test` on authentication failure but `/test` is inaccessible and it ends up showing a generated page.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of `failureUrl` differs based on whether or not a custom `loginPage` is configured.

Since you have not customized `loginPage`, the framework will intercept the failure URL ("/test") and generate the default error page, which is simply the default login page with an error message.
That is why you see the generated login page with accessing "/test".
Your Controller mapping for "/test" is ignored.

To tell the framework not to generate the error page, you can configure the `failureHandler` instead.

```
http
    .oauth2Login((oauth2Login) -> oauth2Login
        .failureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler("/test"))
    );
```

Note: This may be confusing because the Javadoc for `failureUrl` does not describe its behaviour properly. I have created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9229) in the Spring Security backlog to fix this.

Comment: I kind of understand what you mean but my thought was that since I have set the `/test` url as `permitAll` this should not happen and `/test` should be available since it bypasses authentication. Is my thought incorrect?

Comment: @Konstantine The endpoint `/test` is available to all users, but the problem is that rather than using your Controller and rendering "test.html", the Spring Security filter is intercepting any requests to `/test` and rendering the error page (=the login page) instead. I'm not sure that this is happening, but it's my best guess. You can confirm by looking at the networking tab in your browser. If you access "/test", does it redirect to "/login"? That would mean that "/test" is secured. Or does it just render the page? That means that the filter is intercepting it and setting the response.